# App crashes when Display Images from (Database) json into viewpager

Tags: android, json, android-viewpager

I want to display images from database into imageslider for which i am using viewpager. When i put the images in the drawable, the code works fine. However when I take the images from the database the app crashes. Please look through my code and help me with it

SliderActivity.java

```
public class SliderActivity extends Activity{
JSONObject jsonobject; 
JSONArray jsonarray;
String[] imageurl;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ViewPager mPager;
CirclePageIndicator indicator;
ArrayList<String> imageList ;
ArrayList<String> ImagesArray;
int i;
/*private static final Integer[] IMAGES= {
     R.drawable.image1,
     R.drawable.image2,
     R.drawable.image3,
     R.drawable.image4};
    private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();*/
    private static int currentPage = 0;
    private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
            @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider);
      new DownloadJSON().execute();
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        CirclePageIndicator indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        //  init();
            }
class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
                    }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.10.63/get_for_slider.php");
            try{
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("images");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String s = jsonobject.getString("image1");
                    Log.e("",s);
                    String s1 = jsonobject.getString("image2");
                    String s2 = jsonobject.getString("image3");
                    imageurl = new String[]{
                            s,s1,s2 } ; 
                    }
                    }

                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;    
                }
                protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                     for(i=0;i<imageurl.length;i++)
                            ImagesArray.add(imageurl[i]);
                            Log.e("post block","" + imageurl[i]);
                            mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingAdapterActivity(SliderActivity.this,ImagesArray));
                            indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
                            final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                            //Set circle indicator radius
                            indicator.setRadius(3 * density);
                             NUM_PAGES =imageurl.length;
                             Log.e("","" + NUM_PAGES);
                            // Auto start of viewpager
                            final Handler handler = new Handler();
                            final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                                        currentPage = 0;
                                    }
                                    mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                                }
                            };
                            Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
                            swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                public void run() {
                                    handler.post(Update);
                                }
                            }, 3000, 3000);

                            // Pager listener over indicator
                            indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                                    currentPage = position;

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            }
   }
```

my Adapterclass SliderAdapterActivity.java

```
 public class SlidingAdapterActivity extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> IMAGES;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public SlidingAdapterActivity(Context context,ArrayList<String> IMAGES) {
        this.context = context;
        this.IMAGES=IMAGES;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return IMAGES.size();
    }
     @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_sliding_adapter, view, false);
            assert imageLayout != null;
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
           Picasso.with(context).load(IMAGES.get(position)).into(imageView);
           // imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES.get(position));
            view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view.equals(object);
    }
     @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }


         @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View) object);
            }
}
```

Logcat :

```
   05-11 12:36:24.347: E/(740): image1.jpg
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.example.imageslider.SliderActivity$DownloadJSON.onPostExecute(SliderActivity.java:83)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.example.imageslider.SliderActivity$DownloadJSON.onPostExecute(SliderActivity.java:1)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-11 12:36:24.367: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the log trace

Comment: What Exception you are getting ?

Comment: which datatype of image you can use to store image in database?? BLOB or STRING?

Comment: posted the log @nitesh i have put only images' name in the database, the images are stored in the www folder

Comment: Firstly initialise array list like this private ArrayList<String> ImagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();  Then insert image object in this array list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your onPostExecute Method :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
    ImagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                         for(i=0;i<imageurl.length;i++)
                                ImagesArray.add(imageurl[i]);
                                Log.e("post block","" + imageurl[i]);
                                mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingAdapterActivity(SliderActivity.this,ImagesArray));
                                indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
                                final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                                //Set circle indicator radius
                                indicator.setRadius(3 * density);
                                 NUM_PAGES =imageurl.length;
                                 Log.e("","" + NUM_PAGES);
                                // Auto start of viewpager
                                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                                            currentPage = 0;
                                        }
                                        mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                                    }
                                };
                                Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
                                swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        handler.post(Update);
                                    }
                                }, 3000, 3000);

                                // Pager listener over indicator
                                indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                                        currentPage = position;

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

                                    }
                                });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey kindly initialize the array List

```
ArrayList<String> ImagesArray;
```

So its show null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onPostExecute...`

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
  ImagesArray = new ArrayList<String>();//Initialisation than add items
                 for(i=0;i<imageurl.length;i++)
                        ImagesArray.add(imageurl[i]);
```